# avoid and observeEvent triggers another

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I use two observeEvents,
one on selectInput and another on a map_shape_click.

The map_shape_click updates the values on the selectInput.

How can avoid that the selectinput value is triggered after the map_shape_click,
while maintaining a trigger when only the selectInput is changed?

see code below. When the poly line is clicked, the dropdown event is triggered. How can this be avoided?

```
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  selectInput("test", "test", c("value 1", "value 2", "value 3", "X")),
  p(),
  textOutput("selected_var")
  )
)

df <- data.frame (lat = c(41.82, 46.88, 41.48, 39.14), lon = c(-88.32, -124.10, -88.33, -114.90))

server <- shinyServer (function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet('map',height = "100%") %>% addTiles()
  })

  observe({
    leafletProxy('mymap') %>% addPolylines(data = df, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lon, layerId="test", group = "test")
  })

  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_click,{
    print ("shapeclicked")
    output$selected_var <-renderText ("shapeclicked")
    updateSelectInput(session, "test", selected = "X")
    })


  observeEvent(input$test, {
    print ("dropdown triggered")
    output$selected_var <-renderText ("dropdown triggered")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: quick code added